# Formula for refraction between two mirrors

Tags: geometry

i have a question about refraction. A light beam is sent diagonally into two parallel mirrors. Now i want to get the distance y depending on x. Is there a general formula ?
In my example the two parallels are always 60 units apart, but the angle of the input ray is variable. Also, if there is no formula, is there any way to solve this problem programmatically?

[image]

Thanks

Comment: It doesn't belong under the "logic" tag.

Comment: In this scenario, the total length of the zig-zag equals the length of the long straight line shown

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen SCPhantom wants the $y$ in the diagram.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\theta$ be the positive angle between the ray and the $x$-axis. Let $h$ be the distance between the two mirrors. In this case, $h=60$.

Let $d$ be the horizontal distance travelled by the ray in going (once) from one mirror to the other mirror. Then, $$d = \dfrac{h}{\tan{\theta}}.$$

With $y=f(x)$ as the required function,

$$f(x) =
\begin{cases}
h - \left(x - \left\lfloor \frac{x}{d} \right\rfloor d\right)\tan{\theta},  & \text{if $\left\lfloor \frac{x}{d} \right\rfloor$ is even (ray is going down)} \\
\left(x - \left\lfloor \frac{x}{d} \right\rfloor d\right)\tan{\theta}, & \text{if $\left\lfloor \frac{x}{d} \right\rfloor$ is odd (ray is going up).}
\end{cases}
$$